# Apache Solr: Can I use solr stats component?

Tags: solr

I am using solr for indexing data.  I need some statistics information like "max , min , stddev" from indexed data. I read about `SolrStatsComponent` and I used this too.

I read this line on `apache_solr_4_cookbook.pdf`

"Please be careful when using this component on the multivalued fields as it can be a 
performance bottleneck."

**My Solr Query**

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/daycore/select?q=*:*&stats=true&stats.field=login_attempts&rows=0
```

Can I use this query?

**`schema.xml`**

```
<field name="login_attempts" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

Is it affect solr performance?

Comment: Is your `login_attempts` field multiValued? If so could you copy this data to another field that is not multiValued and use that for terms analysis.

Comment: @PaigeCook , I doesn't understand what is mean by multiValued?

Answer (score 0):

You are fine to use the query that you have specified against the `login_attempts` field you have defined. It is a not a multiValued field. A multiValued field would have the attribute `multiValued="true"` specified in the schema, which you do not have and is defined as

> field may contain multiple values per document, i.e. if it can appear multiple times in a document

For more information, please refer to [SchemaXml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) on the Solr wiki.